# Page not loading with proxy but works without

Tags: java, selenium, proxy

So I'm trying to implement proxy support for an application I'm making and for some reason when I try to use a proxy and then try loading a page the page just takes a while to load and then just says it could not connect. If I don't use the proxy the page loads just fine.

My code looks like the following.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    String PROXY = "24.12.132.36:21872";

    org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY).setFtpProxy(PROXY).setSslProxy(PROXY);
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);

    driver.get("https://www.google.ca/");

}
```

Note: Code was taken from the selenium website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct so my assumption is that the proxies ip/port are wrong or that the proxy is refusing your connection, try to use this proxy in a browser manually and check to see if you can connect to the website you are trying.